# How to embed tweets in R markdown documents being knit to HTML?

Tags: r, r-markdown, rtweet

It is fairly easy to embed tweets into blog post using the `blogdown` R package and Hugo shortcodes as described at https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/content.html.

I would like to embed tweets in an R markdown document that is being knit to a standalone HTML document. What is the best way to do this? It looks like Twitter provides an Embed Tweet functionality that I can use interactively to get HTML to embed a tweet, but I need to do this programmatically, given a tweet id.

Comment: A number of solutions have been proposed on Twitter at https://twitter.com/alexpghayes/status/1211748406730706944

Answer (score 3):

For people who don't want to go to twitter, the thread includes recommendations for two packages. `twittrmd` and `twitterwidget`. I was able to get `twittrmd` to work as follows:

### Install packages

This was the hard part, because the CRAN `webshot2` repo wasn't compatible with my R environment.

```
devtools::install_github("gadenbuie/tweetrmd")

# necessary if your output type is not html (as far as I can tell)
devtools::install_github("rstudio/webshot2")

# this is a webshot2 requirement
install.packages("magick")
```

### Use packages

With these packages you can capture a screenshot by

```
library(twittrmd)
include_tweet("https://twitter.com/nomadj1s/status/1294390352904966151")
```

If your output type is not html, `tweetrmd` will rendered as a png or pdf. In any case, I think you can only see the tweet upon knitting.

More info is available on the [github](https://github.com/gadenbuie/tweetrmd), including helper functions to build twitter urls from a username and tweet_id and ideas about how to use `memoise` to keep a copy of the tweet in the case that it's removed from twitter.

Comment: Successfully added to https://filipezabala.com/eb/visualizacao.html.